# Can't get total hours displayed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I need to create a registration page for my javascript class. By using local storage, the program needs to allow a student to register for 4 class, each being a total of 3 credit hours. When you click the display you should see the classes registered and the total credit hours. So if a student registers for all 4 classes, the total hours should be 12. If a student registered for 3 classes, the total should be 9 and etc. If a student drops a class, the result should read null. The classes display but the total credit hours is set to 0. How can I fix this? Here is what I have:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Class Registration</title>
<style>
body {
    background-color:lightblue;
}
</style>
<script>
function storeTask(task) {
    var taskDetail = document.getElementById(task).value;
    localStorage.setItem(task, taskDetail); 
}

function getTask(task) {
    document.getElementById(task).value = localStorage.getItem(task);
}

function clearTask(task) {
    localStorage.removeItem(task);
    document.getElementById(task).value="";
}

function displayTasks() {
    var intTotal =0;
    if (localStorage.getItem('Class1') != null) {
    }
    outputResults = document.getElementById("Results");
    outputResults.innerHTML = 
        'Class 1: ' + localStorage.getItem('class1') + '<br />' +
        'Class 2: ' + localStorage.getItem('class2') + '<br />' +
        'Class 3: ' + localStorage.getItem('class3') + '<br />' +
        'Class 4: ' + localStorage.getItem('class4') + '<br />' +
        '<br />' +
        'Total Class Hours: ' + intTotal +
        '';
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td valign="top">

<div id="outer">
<h1>Local Storage</h1>
My Upcoming Classes
<br><br>
Class 1:
<select id="class1">
  <option value="">Please Select a Class</option>
  <option value="IT Management">IT Management</option>
  <option value="Multimedia Technology">Multimedia Technology</option>
  <option value="Multimedia Authoritizing">Multimedia Authoritizing</option>
  <option value="Web Site Development">Web Site Development</option>


&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="Register" 
    onclick="storeTask('class1');">
    <input type="button" value="Drop" 
    onclick="clearTask('class1');">
<br><br>
 Class 2:
<select id="class2">
  <option value="">Please Select a Class</option>
  <option value="IT Management">IT Management</option>
  <option value="Multimedia Technology">Multimedia Technology</option>
  <option value="Multimedia Authoritizing">Multimedia Authoritizing</option>
  <option value="Web Site Development">Web Site Development</option>
&nbsp;  
    <input type="button" value="Register" 
    onclick="storeTask('class2');">
    <input type="button" value="Drop" 
    onclick="clearTask('class2');">
<br><br>
Class 3:
    <select id="class3">
  <option value="">Please Select a Class</option>
  <option value="IT Management">IT Management</option>
  <option value="Multimedia Technology">Multimedia Technology</option>
  <option value="Multimedia Authoritizing">Multimedia Authoritizing</option>
  <option value="Web Site Development">Web Site Development</option>

    &nbsp; 
    <input type="button" value="Register" 
    onclick="storeTask('class3');">
    <input type="button" value="Drop" 
    onclick="clearTask('class3');">
<br><br>
Class 4:
    <select id="class4">
  <option value="">Please Select a Class</option>
  <option value="IT Management">IT Management</option>
  <option value="Multimedia Technology">Multimedia Technology</option>
  <option value="Multimedia Authoritizing">Multimedia Authoritizing</option>
  <option value="Web Site Development">Web Site Development</option>
    &nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="Register" 
    onclick="storeTask('class4');">
    <input type="button" value="Drop" 
    onclick="clearTask('class4');">

</div>
</td>

<td valign="top">
Output Results
<br>
<input type="button" value="Display Tasks"
    onclick="displayTasks();">

<div id="Results"></div>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks like a homework.

Comment: I didn't see you ever changed intTotal in dislayTasks().

Answer (score 0):

You could have a global variable which you increment by 3 every time you store an item. Then you use that variable on the other parts of the code where you need it. I think this should get you going towards figuring this one out without completely handing it to you if this is indeed homework.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be close. You are resetting `intTotal` to 0 every time that you call `displayTasks`, but you are never incrementing it by 3 every time that you store one of the items. Similar to what @carlosHT mentioned, you will want to store that total somewhere accessible and access it to increment it each time you store an item. I would avoid using a global variable if possible. Hopefully that doesn't give away too much.